# push notification to client browser without client request in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, push-notification, mean

I am developing a web app using MEAN (Angular 6) in which I want that when some changes in database occur, server sends the response to the particular client. And I want this notification to be sent client's browser.

Is it possible to send response to particular client without client's request?.
can someone share an example? or can someone share process for it?

which steps need to follow to achieve notification in web app?

Answer (score 0):

That would be violating user's freedom. You have to ask for permission.